# Custom caching for $resource

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-resource, angular-http

I have the following pattern in my AngularJS which calls for refactoring:

```
$scope.advertisers = Advertiser.query()
$scope.advertisersMap = {};
$scope.advertiser.$then(function (response) {
    arrayToMap(response.resource, $scope.advertisersMap)
}
```

`arrayToMap` is function that adds each item in an array to the object with it's ID as key.

Now, I would have liked that this will happen in `Advertiser` itself, e.g.

```
$scope.allAdvertisers = Advertiser.query()
// Somewhere else
var advertiser = Advertiser.get({id: 2})
```

Where `Advertiser.get({id: 2})` will return from a cache populated earlier by the query method.

`Advertiser` is defined in factory:

```
.factory('Advertiser', ['djResource', 'Group', function ($djResource, Group) {

    var Advertiser = $djResource('/campaigns/advertisers/:advertiserId/', {advertiserId: '@id'});

    Advertiser.prototype.getGroups = function () {
        return Group.getByAdvertiser({advertiserId: this.id});
    };
    return Advertiser;
}])
```

Sadly, DjangoRestResource (and $resource which it wraps) caches by URLs, so `query()` will cache */advertisers/* while `get(2)` will cache */advertisers/2/*, but I want `query` to cache in such way that `get` will be able to retrieve it as well.

I've tried replacing the `query` function by a wrapper function that does the caching, but I want it to return an promise which is also an Array like $resource does. It was something like:

```
    var oldQuery = Advertiser.query;
    var cache = $cacheFactory('advertisers');
    Advertiser.query = function () {
        var promise = oldQuery();
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            angular.forEach(response.resource, function (resource) {
                cache.put(resource.id, resource)
            })
        })
    };
```

But then the returned promise is no longer an Array-like object, and it doesn't not encapsulate the returned results in an Advertiser object as it used to, which breaks most of my code expects that `Advertiser.query()` will eventually be an Array.

What other approaches should I try? This snippet repeats itself in every controller for multiple factories and it hurts my eyes.

Comment: Is Advertiser a service/factory?

Comment: @JesseBuitenhuis Advertiser is a factory, and it uses an abstraction to resource called "angular-django-rest-resource" which I'm eager to replace. I'll update the question with factory definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution to the problem:

```
function makeCachingMethod(object, method, cache, config) {
    var $q = angular.injector(['services']).get('$q');
    var oldMethod = object[method];
    object[method] = function () {
        var result;
        if (!config.isArray) {
            var id = config.idParam ? arguments[0][config.idParam] : arguments[0];
            result = cache.get(id);
            if (result !== undefined) {
                if (result.$promise === undefined) {
                    result.$promise = $q.when(result);
                    result.$resolved = true;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        result = oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        result.$promise.then(function (data) {
            if (config.isArray) {
                angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
                    cache.put(item.id, item);
                })
            } else {
                cache.put(data.id, data);
            }
            return data;
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

And an example usage:

```
app.factory('Country', ['$resource', '$cacheFactory', function ($resource, $cacheFactory) {
    var Country = $resource('/campaigns/countries/:id', {id: "@id"}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', url: '/campaigns/countries/', isArray: true},
        get: {method: 'GET', url: '/campaigns/countries/:id/', isArray: false}
    });
    var cache = $cacheFactory('countries');
    makeCachingMethod(Country, 'query', cache, {isArray: true});
    makeCachingMethod(Country, 'get', cache, {idParam: 'id'});
    return Country;
}])
```

*What is happening here?*

I use `makeCachingMethod` to decorate the original method created by `$resource`. Following the pattern used by `$resource` itself, I use a configuration object to signal whether the decorated method returns an array or not, on how the id is passed in queries. I assume, though, that the key of the ID to save is 'id', which is correct for my models but might need to be changed.

Noticed that before returning an object from the cache, the decorator adds to it `$promise` and `$resolved` attributes, since my application expects objects originated from `$resource` which have these properties, and in order to keep using the promises API, e.g.:

```
$scope.advertiser = Advertiser.get({advertiserId: $scope.advertiserId});
$scope.advertiser.$promise.then(function () {
    $scope.doSomething();
});
```

Notice that since the function is defined outside the scope of any Angular module it is required to inject the `$q` service using `angular.injector()`. A nicer solution will be to return a service for invoking the decorator function. Such service could also handle the generation of the caches themselves.

This solution does not handle the expiration of cached models, which isn't much of problem in my scenario, as these rarely change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any cache support directly with $resource, you could create a factory that abstracts the Advertiser resource and handle the caching yourself.

Here is some helpful info on caching:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#validating-cached-responses-with-etags

I'm working on an app at the minute using $resource and every method is abstracting so I can check the cache to see if what I'm requesting is there and return it, if not, make the call using $resource.

Comment: This article is not helpful, I need somehow to share a cache between two requests handlers that access different URLs. Most of the models I need to cache rarely change, so determining whether it had changed on the server isn't much of an issue, I can just assume it hasn't if sessions are short enough.
What I am missing is a way to catch the original request, cache it and then propagate it. I'll update with an example that failed.

Comment: A cache is currently supported for angular $resources, see actions section on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage